# cannot log-in user using rspec integration testing

Tags: selenium, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, integration-testing

I am trying to create a test for Login; The functionality has been implemented and working fine but I am trying to create a test for it. However, User model is empty in sessions controller but it has content in the test code. On the code below, I added binding.pry(debugger) to check for the User model.

It's working fine too when I am not using webdriver(js: true), if it's just purely like this:

```
post "/api/user/sign_in", {
  user: {
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  }
}

expect(response).to be_success
```

I've been using the same test code before which is working fine. I am not just sure if it has something to do with my front-end is AngularJS.

**TEST CODE**

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Model, js: true do
  let(:model) { Model }
  let!(:user)  { create(:user) }

  it "Login" do
    binding.pry ### #user exists in User.all #####

    visit root_path
    find('#btn-signin').click
    find('#tab-signin').click

    fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'user_password', with: user.password

    find('#btn-login').click

    binding.pry #### user exists in User.all ####

    expect(page).to have_css '.profile-pic'
  end
end
```

**SESSIONS CONTROLLER**

```
def create
  puts User.pluck(:email).join(', ') #### user does not exists (it's actually blank) ####

  warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")

  render :json => current_user.to_json
end
```

**GEMS**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'codeclimate-test-reporter', require: nil
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'jasmine'

  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.38.0'
end
```

**RAILS SPEC**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.include UserMacros
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Comment: no idea in this case but I have had similar problems in the past and it normally has to do with how database connections are handled. Is `use_transactional_fixtures` the right way to do it?

Comment: hi @froderik, no is the answer to your question. I set it to false then use database_cleaner gem to fix it. Should I delete this question? thanks!

Comment: it is better if you add and accept your own answer so other devs can find the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:
GEMFILE

```
gem 'database_cleaner'
```

RAILS_HELPER.RB
      config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```